# Displaying Database on Listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to create a ListView which displays the contents of my database on an activity in an android application. The method I have attempted crashes the app before it can run. Below is my code for my main activity and sqlhelper class. If anyone could tell me why that would be great thanks.

Main Activity
    package com.mcclure.hannah.books;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.List;
import com.mcclure.hannah.books.MySQLiteHelper;
import com.mcclure.hannah.books.Book;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ListView lv ;
private String TAG="Hannah";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

    /**
     * CRUD Operations
     * */
    // add Books
    db.addBook(new Book("Android Application Development Cookbook", "Wei Meng Lee"));
    db.addBook(new Book("Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide", "Bill Phillips and Brian Hardy"));
    db.addBook(new Book("Learn Android App Development", "Wallace Jackson"));

    // get all books
    List<Book> list = db.getAllBooks();

    // delete one book
    db.deleteBook(list.get(0));

    // get all books
    db.getAllBooks();

    String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);


    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
             this,
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array );
    Log.d(TAG,"**************************");
     lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);



}
```

}

MySQLiteHelper Classs

```
package com.mcclure.hannah.books;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import com.mcclure.hannah.books.Book;
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BookDB";

public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // SQL statement to create book table
    String CREATE_BOOK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE books ( " +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "title TEXT, "+
            "author TEXT )";

    // create books table
    db.execSQL(CREATE_BOOK_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older books table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS books");

    // create fresh books table
    this.onCreate(db);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * CRUD operations (create "add", read "get", update, delete) book + get all books + delete all books
 */

// Books table name
private static final String TABLE_BOOKS = "books";

// Books Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";

private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID,KEY_TITLE,KEY_AUTHOR};

public void addBook(Book book){
    Log.d("addBook", book.toString());
    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, book.getTitle()); // get title
    values.put(KEY_AUTHOR, book.getAuthor()); // get author

    // 3. insert
    db.insert(TABLE_BOOKS, // table
            null, //nullColumnHack
            values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column values

    // 4. close
    db.close();
}

public Book getBook(int id){

    // 1. get reference to readable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // 2. build query
    Cursor cursor =
            db.query(TABLE_BOOKS, // a. table
                    COLUMNS, // b. column names
                    " id = ?", // c. selections
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, // d. selections args
                    null, // e. group by
                    null, // f. having
                    null, // g. order by
                    null); // h. limit

    // 3. if we got results get the first one
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    // 4. build book object
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
    book.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
    book.setAuthor(cursor.getString(2));

    Log.d("getBook("+id+")", book.toString());

    // 5. return book
    return book;
}

// Get All Books
public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
    List<Book> books = new LinkedList<Book>();

    // 1. build the query
    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_BOOKS;

    // 2. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    // 3. go over each row, build book and add it to list
    Book book = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            book = new Book();
            book.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            book.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            book.setAuthor(cursor.getString(2));

            // Add book to books
            books.add(book);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    Log.d("getAllBooks()", books.toString());

    // return books
    return books;
}

// Updating single book
public int updateBook(Book book) {

    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("title", book.getTitle()); // get title
    values.put("author", book.getAuthor()); // get author

    // 3. updating row
    int i = db.update(TABLE_BOOKS, //table
            values, // column/value
            KEY_ID+" = ?", // selections
            new String[] { String.valueOf(book.getId()) }); //selection args

    // 4. close
    db.close();

    return i;

}

// Deleting single book
public void deleteBook(Book book) {

    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. delete
    db.delete(TABLE_BOOKS,
            KEY_ID+" = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(book.getId()) });

    // 3. close
    db.close();

    Log.d("deleteBook", book.toString());

}
```

The error message (stacktrace) diplayed is :

```
04-21 16:12:09.364 6896-6896/com.mcclure.hannah.books E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mcclure.hannah.books, PID: 6896
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mcclure.hannah.books/com.mcclure.hannah.books.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: com.mcclure.hannah.books.Book cannot be stored in an array of type java.lang.String[]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2873)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1482)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: com.mcclure.hannah.books.Book cannot be stored in an array of type java.lang.String[]
        at java.util.LinkedList.toArray(LinkedList.java:958)
        at com.mcclure.hannah.books.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2752)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2873) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1482) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: "Crashes the app" implies that there must be a stacktrace or some error message available. Pleas do always post error details.

Comment: The logcat doesn't show the error it says to much output to process most times.

Comment: Filter your logcat output by app to display only relevant lines.

Comment: Thank you I have added  the error message displayed

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: com.mcclure.hannah.books.Book cannot be stored in an array of type java.lang.String[]`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a Book in a list of String:

```
 String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```